# Where is the printer sharing setting dialog?

Tags: release-freya, networking, printer

HP Laserjet 2100 with parallel port connection connected. Freya sees it fine and prints fine.

But I want to share it with the LAN, but I can't find any settings to make the printer discoverable. CUPS, and the Printer settings application are installed.

However, there is no "share" setting like in Ubuntu 14.04. Networking is working great, and I'd rather not use Samba. Where is the setting?

Comment: The rephrasing of my question and the answer is very much appreciated. However, it would make more sense for an OS trying to be based on a gui to have a more elegant way to the printer-localhost dialog. (Now accessed via slingshot>type-system-config-printers) Wouldn't it be more reasonable if the existing slingshot>system settings>printers had a button that leads to the printers-localhost dialog? (requiring no typing)

Comment: Possibly. I'm not sure it's used enough to be needed. You only have to do this setting once - so why have an app in Slingshot. Maybe in default printers would be good.

Answer (score 4):

First open a terminal and launch `system-config-printers` or search Slingshot for "System-Config".
When it's open it looks like this:

[image]

Right click and check it is shared:

[image]

Now we have to change the server settings as per this instruction:

[image]

[image]

And then check the two check marks `Publish shared printers connected to this system` and optionally `Allow printing from the internet`.

[image]

Then any computer on the network should be able to see it.

Answer (score 2):

Go to http://localhost:631 (web-based-printer-setting), select **Administration** and then checklist *Server Settings* as follows ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To install `system-config-printers` on elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera

```
apt install print-manager
```